# Partial slide android

Tags: android

How do I slide only an part of the screen when changing intent?

For example: prevent the header of the intent to slide when intent is changed.

Or how can I use an intent within another intent and start activities without effecting the main intent.

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking

Answer (score 1):

You can user [ViewFlipper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html). Use the showNext() and showPrevious() to change content. And you can put a header in outer of the viewflipper and it won't flip. The flip can be [animated](http://www.warriorpoint.com/blog/2009/05/26/android-switching-screens-in-an-activity-with-animations-using-viewflipper/).

Comment: But it seems to be very problematic to involve intents with viewflippers